# How to create directory in Android Project Structure Programatically?

Tags: android

Friends! I need to create directory in my android project structure,In directory I want to create a file and download from url.

Comment: What do you mean by download from url? Please elaborate your question. We are not magician.

Comment: Please try to provide some code that you have tried till now, and try to elaborate what you want to do.

Comment: want to create directory programatically

Comment: @UmarZaii I have made one API call , I have got google font url "https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/master/apache/roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf" as response.This url might be differ for every API request. I want to download this ttf into one directory.For this i have two create directory in my project programatically. Hope this will understand u

Comment: You can download the font file and apply the font at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click in the base package, and there you can shoose what you want to create

[image: Create directory]